# Customizing scrollbar in QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, css, qt, browser

The pink 'square' is a `QtWebEngineView` widget, and I'm trying to customize her scrollbar.

In the picture below, what is this thing which I circled red called?

[image]

It only became visible together with the scrollbars.

I'm confused if it's a 'part' of the scrollbars.

This is my current `css` code being applied to the widget:

```
class WebEngine : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    WebEngine(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWebEngineView(parent)
    {
        this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
        this->setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
        this->page()->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);

        insertStyleSheet("scrollbar",
            R"(
                /* Width */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                  width: 10px;
                }
    
                /* Track */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                   display:none;  /* Makes the track transparent */
                }
    
                /* Thumb */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                  border-radius: 12px;
                  background: #160005;
                }
    
                /* Thumb on hover */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
                  background: #2a2a2a;
                }
            )"
            , true);
    }

    void insertStyleSheet(const QString& name, const QString& source, bool immediately)
    {
        QWebEngineScript script;
        QString s = QString::fromLatin1("(function() {"\
            "    css = document.createElement('style');"\
            "    css.type = 'text/css';"\
            "    css.id = '%1';"\
            "    document.head.appendChild(css);"\
            "    css.innerText = '%2';"\
            "})()").arg(name).arg(source.simplified());

        if (immediately)
            this->page()->runJavaScript(s, QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);

        script.setName(name);
        script.setSourceCode(s);
        script.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript::DocumentReady);
        script.setRunsOnSubFrames(true);
        script.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);
        this->page()->scripts().insert(script);
    }
}
```